# Propagation of rpath in library fails

Tags: macos, mach-o, dyld, rpath

**Short question:** Are the rpaths from a `LC_RPATH` command inside a library passed onto subsequent (and indirect) dynamically loaded libraries?

**To be more precise:** I have `libapi.dylib` dynamically linked to `libloader.dylib` which in turn dynamically loads a plugin `libplugin.dylib`. I've got:

```
$ otool -l lib/libapi.dylib
lib/libapi.dylib
        libapi.dylib
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
        @rpath/libloader.dylib

$ otool -l lib/libloader.dylib
lib/libloader.dylib
        libloader.dylib
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

$ otool -l lib/plugins/libplugin.dylib
lib/plugins/libplugin.dylib:
        libplugin.dylib
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
        @rpath/libloader.dylib

$ otool -L lib/libapi.dylib | grep "LC_RPATH" -A2
        cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 32
        path @loader_path/ (offset 12)
```

Neither `libloader.dylib` nor `libplugin.dylib` define a rpath command. And the install names are without any @rpath/ or other paths, although the names in the load commands are prepended by a @rpath/.

The client now loads `libapi.dylib` which in turn is linked to `libloader.dylib`. This library dynamically now loads `libplugin.dylib` which is linked to `libloader.dylib`.

Why can't `libplugin.dylib` by loaded? It quits since it can't find `libloader.dylib` - although it must be already loaded. Why is the rpath @loader_path/ from `libapi.dylib` not properly propagated over `libloader.dylib` to `libplugin.dylib`? Using the DYLD_PRINT_RPATHS environment variable, I can see, that no rpath substitution is tried in order to load `libloader.dylib` in `libplugin.dylib`. What the heck going on here?